# Argparse non mutually exclusive group within a mutually exclusive group

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to accomplish something like

```
[-a] [-b | [[-c | -d] [-e]]]
```

In code, I thought it would look something like

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a')
meg = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=False)
meg.add_argument('-b')
megg = meg.add_argument_group() # <-- The issue is here. I did not realize that this option was purely for visual purposes.
meggmeg = megg.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=False)
meggmeg.add_argument('-c')
meggmeg.add_argument('-d')
megg.add_argument('-e')
parser.parse_args()
```

however, what actually ends up being generated is

```
[-a] [-b] [-c | -d] [-e]
```

This output is strange because even if `add_argument_group()` was purely for visual purposes, the output should still end up being

```
[-a] [-b | [-c | -d] | -e]
```

Even stranger still is the behaviour of the following code if I were to replace `add_argument_group()` with `add_mutually_exclusive_group()`

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a')
meg = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=False)
meg.add_argument('-b')
megg = meg.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
meggmeg = megg.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=False)
meggmeg.add_argument('-c')
meggmeg.add_argument('-d')
megg.add_argument('-e')
parser.parse_args()
```

What I would expect is the following (which is not the behaviour that I want, as I don't want the final mutual exclusion, but it is close)

```
[-a] [-b | [[-c | -d] | -e]]
```

but the actual output that I get is

```
[-a] [-b | [[-c | -d |] -e]]
```

and if I were to add a `megg.add_argument('-f')`, then the output becomes

```
[-a] [-b | [[-c | -d |] -e | -f]]
```

which is just very strange.

Comment: These groups are not designed for nesting..`argument group` only affects the help lines, not parsing or usage. Exclusive group insde an exclusive just parses as one bigger flat exc,usive.  Read the code if you must, but don''t expect to make much sense of this kind of trial and error.

Comment: @hpaulj that's rather unfortunate. Nesting argument groups is somewhat of a basic necessity of command line interfaces, so I'm surprised that it isn't supported. I suppose the only option, then. is to manually hardcode in the logic to check if another argument is present.

Comment: The first case will parse as though `b,c,d,e` are all in one flat group. Usage is 'simple minded' and fragile when displaying nested groups and doesn't reflect actual parsing tests.  I could point you to bug/issue discussions if necessay.  There are also related SO.